# C++ Creating multiple socket clients

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to build a simulation for multiple socket clients.
My server has the following code to listen to multiple clients

My socket are from a very simple class drive from CAsyncSocket and my environment is windows MFC.

```
    m_server.Create(....); // with the correct values
    if (m_server.Listen()==FALSE)
```

and later on the OnSocketAccept() function

```
if (m_server.Accept(tempSock))
{
    CSocketThread* pThread = (CSocketThread*)AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CSocketThread), THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED);
...
```

My simulation apps has the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfClients; i++)
{
    m_sConnected[i].Create();
    int rVal = m_sConnected[i].Connect(csIPAddress.GetString(), m_port);
```

That doesn't work.

In WireShark I can see that my (numOfClients = 10 for example) 10 clients are connected with different client source port.

But each new socket of *m_sConnected[i]* is becoming NULL after the second connection to all sockets including *m_sConnected[0]*.

Closing the sockets or destroy the simulation app create socket close at the server side for all open threads for the listen sockets.

What is the problem?
Can I use the same process/thread for all my socket clients?

10x

UrAv.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are not using the CSocketThread object the right way.
as mentiend in microsoft documention 
after the accept function you need to do the following :

```
CSockThread* pSockThread = (CSockThread*)AfxBeginThread( RUNTIME_CLASS(CSockThread), THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED); 
if (NULL != pSockThread) {
// Detach the newly accepted socket and save
//the SOCKET handle in our new thread object.
//After detaching it, it should no longer be
//used in the context of this thread.
pSockThread->m_hConnected = sConnected.Detach();
pSockThread->ResumeThread(); 
} }
```

when you attach your socket to the thread then it will run.

link to microsoft doc:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxzt95kb.aspx

Comment: Daniel Hi, Thanks for you response. I didn't put all of my code (my mistake). In the server side I'm doing detach and resume. My problem is in the client side - server side open several socket and receive indication to each server thread socket including the indication of socket close.

Comment: do you chane the port? beacuse it looks like your are using the same one

Comment: never mind didnt see that you are using the create function. it will be esier to understund where is the error if you will paste more of your code.

Comment: Update: changing the client to different threads (the same as the server side) solve the problem. Why each client socket has to be in a different thread. It is if I will need different threads to have two descriptors to the same file (to my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

your solution has worked for me. I have used multiple threads to stress test the server in c++ under linux. Pasting my code, it will be helpful to somebody...Experts can improve my code, if they find any flaws in my handling of code. I know, I am doing something wrong but no other go to test the server as no one has provided the solution for this till now. I am able to test the server for 100000 clients using this code. - Kranti.

## include //for threading , link with lpthread

```
void *connection_handler(void *);

#define PORT 9998
#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define MAXSZ 100
#define MAXSOCK 70000

int main()
{
int sockfd[MAXSOCK];//to create socket
int socket_desc , new_socket[MAXSOCK], *new_sock;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;//client will connect on this
int n;
char msg1[MAXSZ];
char msg2[MAXSZ];
int NoOfClients = MAXSOCK;
memset(msg2,0,100);
void *ret;

for(int i=0;i<NoOfClients;i++){
//create socket
sockfd[i]=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
//initialize the socket addresses
memset(&serverAddress,0,sizeof(serverAddress));
serverAddress.sin_family=AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(SERVER_IP);
serverAddress.sin_port=htons(PORT);

//client  connect to server on port
new_socket[i] = connect(sockfd[i],(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress));
printf("new socket connected= %d",new_socket[i]);

pthread_t sniffer_thread[MAXSOCK];
new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));
*new_sock = new_socket[i];
int p=-1;
if( p = pthread_create( &sniffer_thread[i] , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
{
    perror("could not create thread");
    return 1;
}
}
return 0;
}
/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[50];
    printf("we are in connection handler");

    //Send some messages to the server
    message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
    int wlen = write(sock , message , strlen(message));
    printf("write length is %d", wlen);

    //Free the socket pointer
    //close(sock);
    free(sock);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: i missed pthread_join() after the if( p = pthread_create( &sniffer_thread[i] , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
{
    perror("could not create thread");
    return 1;
}